# SIGSEGV Codeblocks

Tags: c

Buenas tardes! Tengo que terminar un trabajo de un juego para la universidad y tengo el típico problema de "a veces funciona". Os cuento por encima: es un juego donde llevas a un personaje, si los enemigos te tocan acaba la partida y vas cogiendo puntos que van apareciendo de forma aleatoria.

```
struct EstrellasRep{
    Estrella * s;
    int maximo, n;
    };

Estrellas EstrellasCrea (int maximo){
    Estrellas e = malloc (sizeof(struct EstrellasRep));
    e->n=0;
    e->maximo=maximo;
    return e;
    }

void EstrellasLibera (Estrellas e){
    for (int i=0; i<e->n; i++) EstrellaLibera(e->s[i]);
    free(e->s);
    free(e);
}
void EstrellasDibuja (Estrellas e){
    for (int i=0; i<e->n; i++) EstrellaDibuja(e->s[i]);
}
int EstrellasColisiona (Estrellas e, int x, int y, int w, int h){
    int i=0;
    int colisiona=0;
    while(i<e->n){
        if (colision(EstrellaGetX(e->s[i]),EstrellaGetY(e->s[i]),EstrellaGetW(e->s[i]), EstrellaGetH(e->s[i]),x,y,w,h))
    {
        EstrellaLibera(e->s[i]);
        e->s[i]=e->s[e->n-1];
        e->n--;
        colisiona++;
    }
    else i++;
}
return colisiona;
}

void EstrellasInserta (Estrellas e, Imagen i, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
     if (e->n<e->maximo) {
        e->s[e->n] = EstrellaCrea(i,x,y,w,h);
        e->n++;
    }
}
```

el sigsev me sale en la línea e->s[e->n] = EstrellaCrea(i,x,y,w,h);

Y ya digo, a veces va xD
Saludos

Edito:

Estrellas es una estructura que lleva al conjunto de Estrella, que son los puntos que hay que recoger. 
    struct EstrellaRep { 
       Imagen i; 
       int x,y,w,h,r,cx,cy; 
       };

```
Estrella EstrellaCrea(Imagen i, int x, int y, int w, int h) { 
    Estrella e = malloc(sizeof(struct EstrellaRep)); 
    e->i=i; 
    e->x=x; 
    e->y=y; 
    e->w=w; 
    e->h=h; 
    return e; 
 }
```

Y Estrella es una clase con su dibujo y coordenadas.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la definición de `Estrellas` y `Estrella`?

Comment: Estrellas es una estructura que lleva al conjunto de Estrella, que son los puntos que hay que recoger.
struct EstrellaRep
{
    Imagen i;
    int x,y,w,h,r,cx,cy;

};

Estrella EstrellaCrea(Imagen i, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    Estrella e = malloc(sizeof(struct EstrellaRep));
    e->i=i;
    e->x=x;
    e->y=y;
    e->w=w;
    e->h=h;
    return e;
    }

Y Estrella es una clase con su dibujo y coordenadas.

Comment: Deberías agregarlo como edición a la pregunta

Comment: estoy seguro que tu problema tiene q ver con las coordenadas pares e impares

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que se me ocurre es que al hacer espacio en la memoria con el EstrellasCrea supongo que querrás hacer un array de punteros a Estrella, (UM xD) tal y como lo estás haciendo has hecho espacio para UN puntero y un int maximo y otro, n. Luego cuando liberas lo "tratas" como si hubieses hecho otro malloc para el array, de manera que hazlo:

Estrellas EstrellasCrea (int maximo){
    Estrellas e = malloc (sizeof(struct EstrellasRep));
    ***e->s = malloc(sizeof(Estrella) * maximo);***
    e->n=0;
    e->maximo=maximo;
    return e;
}

Lo que he hecho ha sido hacer espacio para MAS de una estrella, de hecho, como máximo "maximo" estrella, espero que sea ésto. 
Fdo Israel ;)

Edit : Además dices que la estructura Estrella es struct EstrellaRep { Imagen i; int x,y,w,h,r,cx,cy; }; Estás tratando la estrella como un círculo o como un cuadrado? supongo que como un cuadrado por que cuando creas la estrella la llamas simplemente com imagen i int x int y int w int h... aclara ésto o pasa foto de la estructura y de la función EstrellaCrea() Gracias intentaré ayudarte más tarde.

Comment: Lo primero, muchas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo para contestar, estoy muy agradecida jaja. La estructura estrella es un elemento que tiene una imagen, unas coordenadas, un alto y un ancho.
Perdón, soy nueva en stackoverflow y no sé cómo poner en comentarios el código como en el OP. Pero la función es asignar la memoria con Malloc y a cada variable como la de función.
Estrella EstrellaCrea(Imagen i, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    Estrella e = malloc(sizeof(struct EstrellaRep));
    e->i=i;
    e->x=x;
    e->y=y;
    e->w=w;
    e->h=h;
    return e;
    }